# How to grab a subdirectory name from a directory that I am tracking file size for using DirectoryInfo?

Tags: c#, .net, directoryinfo

I have a simple class I created for a batch process, but I'm having trouble figuring out this issue. I am flagging any files that are over 4KB using DirectoryInfo and sending out an alert email. This works fine for files in the directory that I'm monitoring, but not the folders in the directory. If I have a folder in the directory I'm monitoring, I am getting getting a list of FileInfo()'s, instead of the name of the subdirectory itself. So what I'm asking is, how do I actually monitor the size of the subdirectories and not the files within them?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Hana.BusinessLogicLayer
{
    internal class FileMonitor
    {
        public static bool Process()
        {

            var filewatch = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\me\Desktop\Test");

            List<string> largeFiles = new List<string>(); 

            bool foundfile = false;

            foreach (var f in filewatch.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {

                var theSize = f.Length / 1000;
                
                
                if (theSize > 4) && f.LastWriteTime > DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-15))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("NEW LARGE FILE WRITTEN: {0} is {1}KB.", f.Name, theSize);
                    largeFiles.Add(f.Name);
                    foundfile = true;
                }

                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("SMALL FILE: {0} is small and does not matter", f.Name);
                }

                

                if (foundfile)
                {
                    var sendMail = Utility.SMTPUtil.SendMailCustom(initiatingUserId: 1,
                                                toAddresses: new List<string> { "email@email.com" },
                                                subject: "File Manager Test",
                                                bcc: new List<string> { "email@email.com" },
                                                body: f.Name + " is " + theSize + "KB and the last 
                                                write time was " + f.LastWriteTime
                                                );
                    Console.WriteLine("Email about large file sent");
                    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime());
                    if (!sendMail.Success)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                }

            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue . . .");
            Console.ReadLine();
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The DirectoryInfo class doesn't have any concept of folder size. I think your best bet is to iterate through each subdirectory (probably recursively) and add up the sizes of the files within.

Comment: Is there a way to at least define the name of the folder that the file is coming from?

Comment: If you only care about the sizes of any individual directory (rather than just the top level directories as a whole) you could group by the Directory property on each FileInfo object. If you only care about the top level directories, you probably want to stop using the AllDirectories search option in your GetFiles call, and instead iterate over the directories using the GetDirectories method. In that case, it'd probably be best to do a loop over the directories from GetDirectories, calling GetFiles with AllDirectories on each of them and adding up the file sizes.